# How to run many sites on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, devops

I want to create 50-100 simple sites according to the template on AWS as automated as possible every day. Sites are the same, but must have a different domain and ip. How is it best to implement, what services or turnkey solutions will help?
Thank!

Comment: What is a "site"? Is it just static web pages? Or is it an app? Why do they need different IP addresses? You could run Apache virtual hosts with different domains but the same IP address. Please edit your question to provide more information about your setup, and what you are wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker and run them on different ports.